# PUT and POST not working from J2SE platform (RESTLET Version 3.0-M1)

Tags: java, json, restlet

I'm working on a project with GWT and J2SE clients. The GWT part is working great, but now there are problems with the J2SE client;

> "The server understands the content type of the request entity and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct but was unable to process the
>   contained instructions"
>
> "The serialized representation must have this media type:
>   application/x-java-serialized-object or this one:
>   application/x-java-serialized-object+xml"

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

This code was working some months/versions ago... Both PUT and POST produce this error while GET is working. **Whats wrong here?**

Here's a really simple test case

// Shared Interface

```
public interface J2SeClientServerResourceInt
{
   @Post("json")
   public J2seStatusDto postJ2seStatus(J2seStatusDto pJ2seStatusDto);
}
```

// Java Bean

```
  public class J2seStatusDto implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6901448809350740172L;

        private String mTest;

        public J2seStatusDto()
        {
        }

        public J2seStatusDto(String pTest)
        {
            setTest(pTest); 
        }

        public String getTest()
        {
            return mTest;
        }

        public void setTest(String pTest)
        {
            mTest = pTest;
        }
    }
```

// Server

```
public class J2seServerResource extends ClaireServerResource implements J2SeServerResourceInt
{
    @Override
    public J2seStatusDto postJ2seStatusDto(J2seStatusDto pJ2seStatusDto)
    {
        return pJ2seStatusDto;
    }
}
```

// J2SE Client

```
public class ClaireJsSeTestClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Reference lReference = new Reference("http://localhost:8888//rest/j2se");
        ClientResource lClientResource = new ClientResource(lReference);
        lClientResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        J2SeServerResourceInt lJ2SeServerResource = lClientResource.wrap(J2SeServerResourceInt.class);
        J2seStatusDto lJ2seStatusDto = new J2seStatusDto("TEST");
        J2seStatusDto lJ2seResultDto = lJ2SeServerResource.postJ2seStatusDto(lJ2seStatusDto);
    }
}
```

// Maven J2Se Client

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

// Maven GAE Server

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.gwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-M1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: When debugging with breakpoints in the J2seServerResource, a PUT request reaches the server with payload NULL and a POST doesn't even reach the server (and gives the error message). A GET request works fine...

Comment: When tested with Chrome REST Console the server works fine, the J2SE Client is the problem...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en

Comment: Switching from JSON to XML gives the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thierry Boileau fixed our problem (mistake);

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1029#issuecomment-76212062

Due to the constraints of the GAE platform (there is no support of chunked encoding) you have to specify that the request entity is buffered first;

```
cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
```

Thanks for the great support at restlet.com